# Put vertical spacing among items using

Tags: html, css, angular, flexbox, font-awesome

I have a component that simulates a badge. This component has the following CSS:

[image]

HTML:

```
  <div class="label label-as-badge">
      {{ value.Termo }}
      <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.label-as-badge {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 5px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #0066ba;
}
```

I need to place it in a flex div, placing vertical spaces between them, but because of the padding, they look overlaid.

[image]

how can I give the right vertical spacing bewtween my items?

My div HTML:

```
 <div class="badges">
  <app-badges
  *ngFor="let badge of badges"
  [value]=badge>
  </app-badges>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.badges {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
```

I already tried using

*margin-bottom*

property, but didn't work.

Comment: We need to see your relevant HTML in the question as well.

Comment: Ok! I've edited it. 
I'm using angular.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with this system. Does `app-badges` get replaced with the badges, or do the badges fill it? If the latter, then you need to give app-badges the class `badges`.

Comment: The only other reason I could see this happening is if the `label` class does something wonky.

Comment: the label class was messing this up!!!

Comment: @paulotarcio If you found the answer (it sounds like you did), please post that as an answer explaining what the issue was and how you resolved it, and then mark it as the solution so future readers who have the same problem know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The label class was giving me a strange space, I removed it and it worked.